# A little trouble with jquery-ui effect() function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

It's a simple effect function. It will run the follow code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('button').click(function(){
           $(this).effect('shake','slow');
       })
    })
```

My problem is that the button and its border are both shaking. How do I get the button to shake without the border?

Comment: Can you provide a snippet or fiddle to demo?

Answer (score 0):

In fact the effect always work on div,so I put a div before button.

Comment: @RyanLittle Yeah I think that is what he is saying. He put the button in a div and applied the shake to the div only.